# does Astyanax support cql 3 prepared statements?

Tags: astyanax, cql3

I know that cassandra does but what about Astyanax? And does it escape single quotes in values? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does,

You can see an example here https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Cql-and-cql3

```
final String INSERT_STATEMENT = "INSERT INTO employees (empID, deptID, first_name,   last_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";

result = keyspace
    .prepareQuery(CQL3_CF)
        .withCql(INSERT_STATEMENT)
    .asPreparedStatement()
        .withIntegerValue(222)
        .withIntegerValue(333)
        .withStringValue("Eric")
        .withStringValue("Cartman")
    .execute();
```